# numberofRowsInSection with 2 counts

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6

I have got a json result, that looks like this:

```
[{
    "EventDate": "2015-02-19",
    "PubEvents": [{
        "Title": "Ladies Night",
        "Description": "Every thursday is Ladies Night at the Irish House.\nLadies: 2 cocktails for the price of 1 - 1 pint of Crowmoor Cider - 30 kr",
        "EventType": "LadiesNight",
        "Start": "2015-02-19",
        "End": "2015-02-20",
        "StartTime": "19:00",
        "EndTime": "02:00",
        "Image": "ladies.jpg"
    }, {
        "Title": "Pat Kelly",
        "Description": "Pat Kelly from Ireland has extensive experience in entertaining all nationalities, as he has travelled around the world from New York to Amsterdam. He has a very wide repertoire maintaining a traditional approach, and is well received and appreciated for his ability to get his audience excited every night he hits the stage. A “sure thing” evening you will get with the talented Pat.",
        "EventType": "Music",
        "Start": "2015-02-19",
        "End": "2015-02-20",
        "StartTime": "21:30",
        "EndTime": "01:00",
        "Image": "http://irishhouse.appninja.dk/Images/Musicians/kelly"
    }],
    "Matches": [{
        "EventType": "Sports",
        "Start": "2015-02-19",
        "End": "2015-02-19",
        "StartTime": "18:00",
        "EndTime": "19:00",
        "HomeTeam": {
            "Id": 0,
            "TeamName": "Hold",
            "HomeImageUrl": "defaultHome.png",
            "AwayImageUrl": "defaultAway.png",
            "Badge": "defaultBadge.png"
        },
        "AwayTeam": {
            "Id": 0,
            "TeamName": "AndetHold",
            "HomeImageUrl": "defaultHome.png",
            "AwayImageUrl": "defaultAway.png",
            "Badge": "couldn't get an away team"
        }
    }]
}, {
    "EventDate": "2015-02-20",
    "PubEvents": [{
        "Title": "Pat Kelly",
        "Description": "Pat Kelly from Ireland has extensive experience in entertaining all nationalities, as he has travelled around the world from New York to Amsterdam. He has a very wide repertoire maintaining a traditional approach, and is well received and appreciated for his ability to get his audience excited every night he hits the stage. A “sure thing” evening you will get with the talented Pat.",
        "EventType": "Music",
        "Start": "2015-02-20",
        "End": "2015-02-21",
        "StartTime": "22:30",
        "EndTime": "02:00",
        "Image": "http://irishhouse.appninja.dk/Images/Musicians/kelly"
    }],
    "Matches": []
},
```

An Array of Events in the format:

```
var eventDate : String?
var pubEvents : Array<PubEvent>?
var matches : Array<Match>?
```

numberOfSectionsInTableView is eventarray.count, as every date is distinct

I am struggling with numberOfRowsInSection. It should be either

```
self.eventarray[section].pubEvents?.count or self.eventarray[section].matches?.count
```

depending on which has the highest count.

This is my first attempt of doing Swift, and I'd appreciate a point in the right direction. I tried this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var returncount : Int = 1
        if let pubeventscount = self.eventarray[section].pubEvents?.count{
            if let sportscount = self.eventarray[section].matches?.count{
                if pubeventscount > sportscount{
                    returncount = pubeventscount
                }
                else{
                    returncount = sportscount
                }
            }
        }
        return returncount

    }
```

But no result

Comment: How about `max(eventarray[section].pubEvents?.count ?? 0,  eventarray[section].matches?.count ?? 0)`?

Comment: I'd suggest refactoring your `Event` type to have `pubEvents` and `matches` be non-optional. There's no semantic difference between an empty array (i.e., no events) and a nil optional array (perhaps it means uninitialized, but I don't see the benefit). With non-optional arrays you can just use: `return max(eventarray[section].pubEvents.count, eventarray[section].matches.count)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what "no result" means, but.

Your function can be simplified as:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let event = self.eventarray[section]
    let matchesCount = event.matches?.count ?? 0
    let pubEventsCount = event.pubEvents?.count ?? 0
    return max(matchesCount, pubEventsCount, 1)
}
```

Comment: I've actually got this all wrong. What i needed was their count combined. On the first date I have 2 pub events and 1 match, so I'd need 3 in that section.
Is it even possible to do cellforrowatindexpath with 2 different arrays? Or should i make 2 tables for my events